# Appending property to stdClass Object in PHP while in loop

Tags: php

Looping through an Array of stdClass Objects,  I'd like to add a new property to the Object.
Of all the ways I've tried and researched, none end up adding the new property.

```
Array 
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12345678
            [profile] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => superAdmin
                )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 89101112
            [profile] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => admin
                )
        )
)
```

I have a function that takes in the above array, and then should iterate through it, if certain criteria met, add a new property to the object, and return the array.

```
public function addToProfile($usernameArr) {

      $users = $usernameArr;

      foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
        if (in_array("admin", $user->profile->type)) {
          $users[$key]->profile->newProperty = "newItem";
        }
      }

      return $users;

    }
```

I've also tried the `json_decode(json_encode($users), true)` way which did not end up with the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Your use of `in_array()` should be throwing an error

Comment: @PatrickQ it does indeed. I _did_ have some other code in place of `in_array` while testing a few different iterations, and had something without error in the `if` block, but it would still not add the new property.

Comment: Okay, and do you understand what the error ("in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given") is telling you?

Comment: I do, I mistakenly am pointing to a string and not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I try and avoid doing things like `(object)array(...)` and `json_decode(json_encode())` in PHP as it is not immediately clear to the reader why your doing this round about stuff, so I will provide an alternative answer.

```
 function addNewProp(array $users, $propName, $propVal)
 {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
        // You may need to do extra checking here if profile and type are not required.
        if (isset($users[$i]->profile->type->admin)) {
            $users[$i]->profile->$propName = $propVal;
        }
    }
    return $users;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via transformation `$user object` to the array and back to object:

```
foreach ($users as $key=>&$user) {
    if (in_array("admin", $user->profile->type)) {

        // represents current $user->profile object as an array    
        $tmp = json_decode(json_encode($user->profile),true); 
        // add a new index
        $tmp['newproperty'] = "$key newItem"; 
        // transform back to an object
        $user->profile = (object)($tmp); 
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/OMqqn)**

You can put it into the function like:

```
 function addNewProp($data, $prop_name, $prop_val){

    foreach ($data as $key=>$user) {
        if (in_array("admin", $user->profile->type)) {

            $tmp = json_decode(json_encode($user->profile),true); 
            $tmp[$prop_name] = $prop_val;
            $user->profile = (object)($tmp); 
        }
    }
    return $data;
 }
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3bZHD)**

Your input value of `type` has string datatype. Instead of

```
if (in_array("admin", $user->profile->type)) {
```

you should use

```
if ($user->profile->type === "admin") {
```